# I have an old B&D router and I don’t know how to put the bits on

Tags: routers

[image][image][image]I have an older 5/8 hp Black and Decker router. I want to learn how to use it but I am pretty sure I’m missing a piece to connect the bits. There is a piece that connects to the router but that’s it, I’m not sure what’s missing or if anything actually is. I have a picture included with the only piece I have to hold the bits on. Any help or info would be great! I added a few more pictures but I think that the collet it what’s missing. Thanks everyone. [image]

Comment: It looks like you have a collet chuck there, which is the normal common way to attach bits to routers and dremels. If there’s a part missing, it looks like it might be the outer collar. But you might be able to thread the female nut on the male end a quarter turn, then slide the bit into the opening and tighten the nut. If the bit is solidly in place once the nut is tightened then you are good to go.

Comment: Might be missing the collet itself (internal to the nut) - have you got a model number? - the description is a bit vague for finding matching parts, a model number helps immensely. Be very careful when turning it on - unlike most newer routers whih have "soft-start" features, the old ones tend to kick viciously when you turn the switch on. You have to be ready for that.

Comment: Is it a 7600? Terrible scan of the User Manual here: https://usermanual.wiki/Document/BlackDecker760004760404RouterManual.1026395918/view

Comment: I applaud you for wanting to continue to use old tools instead of just buying shiny new things. HOWEVER, a **STRONG** word of caution: Routers will spin very sharp, potentially heavy chunks of metal at upwards of 20,000 RPM. If you're not 100% sure that the bit is securely in the collet, I'd skip using it. That spinning hunk of metal _will_ eat right through your finger if given a chance! The few bucks on a new tool is far less expensive than the ER bill and possibly spending the rest of your life without a finger. **Please use caution!**

Comment: Personal tale: I thought routers were scary pieces of excrement because what we had growing up were a Sears Craftsman and a B&D that was prone to "self-adjusting" (would change cutting depth in the middle of a cut all by itself.) They were not quality tools. When I finally got a decent router, it was an entirely different experience - they are still tools that will happily cut you, but at least it was not vibrating and twitching and self-adjusting to TRY and cut you. A modern soft-start router of decent quality might be a worthwhile investment.

Comment: Variable speed and a 1/2" as well as 1/4" collet are other features to look for. If you actually use the router for much of anything, the cost of a decent new router will not be large compared to the cost of decent bits - meanwhile, there are a lot of things you can do with router jigs that can save you having to buy other tools (such as jointers and planers) if your needs allow doing the same jobs a bit slower with the router.

Comment: So I need to put baseboard and trim all through my house I’m fixing up and it’s all pretty expensive compared to when I started almost two years ago, so I figured I could try making some baseboard and things myself. I’m pretty new to this type of stuff but I’ve used power tools a lot just nothing like making cabinets or tables or baseboard. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: You're definitely missing the collet, per your updated pictures.

Comment: I'm finding a suspicious lack of spare parts support for this model. Found  a part number and image of the missing part, but it was listed as discontinued. I'd take that (and the fact that it appears substandard in clamping design) as a sign to get a newer router....

Comment: I 100% applaud your efforts to make it yourself, @NoahPrice, but unless you're doing some very simple shapes, you're going to need a powerful router and a router table for making trim, especially in large quantities. That 5/8HP router isn't going to cut it (pun intended). It's time for an upgrade - a kit with a motor and 2 bases (very helpful) can be had for about $200. What you save on lumber will pay for the tool. Also, you've now posted the same image 3 times, please edit again to include the other pics or delete the duplicates. ;)

Comment: Yea I was having trouble trying to delete the duplicates and put the new ones on here…

Answer (score 4):

The inside of the nut you show should be tapered. Then there should be an inner "sleeve" with a matching outer taper and it should be split or have cuts in it to allow it to compress around the shank of the bit you choose to fit.

If that has not been apart for a while then the inner collar may be stuck inside that nut.

Comment: Or, the "sleeve" (collet) may be missing altogether.